# Remove Minecraft gamerules in-game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to remove Minecraft gamerules in-game?

I made a gamerule "New" and now want to remove it but I can't find a way to do it.

I searched in the minecraft help list and found nothing.

I also tried `/gamerule` and found nothing.

Comment: It is not possible to make a gamerule neither to remove one you are only able to set a value... What is your question???

Comment: My question was "Is there a way to remove minecraft gamerules in-game?"

Comment: @Gerret As of the latest snapshots, it is possible to create your own gamerules.

Comment: @colorfusion well i tried it out on 1.7.10 and also the wiki shows no information about that... would be a useful information in the question if he is using a development build...

Comment: @Gerret It's in the prerelease which, if all goes well, will be the official  1.8. The wiki DOES have information about creating new gamerules.

Comment: @colorfusion well ok I found it was a little bit hidden I also was more in the 1.7 and not in a development version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no command to remove a custom gamerule **in-game**. It is, however, possible with a program such as [NBTEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1260521-nbtedit).

Open up your world file, and navigate to level.dat > Data > Gamerules. 
[image]

Within those gamerules you should see the one you created. Select it, and press delete. When you save and open up your world, it should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any programs, remove the gamerule by doing this:

```
/gamerule new 0
```

That will turn the gamerule off. Next, remove everything that makes it work. For example: delete any command blocks that make the gamerule function.

Answer (score -2):

If u mean u have made a gamerule true or false just type the same thing but using the opposite. Example:You've just done /gamerule keepInventory true to turn this off do
/gamerule keepInventory false